# The Collection is empty when the class is accessed externally

Tags: json, swift

I created a class (Cards) that holds a collection of a class called tWelcomeItem. The SendRequest function decodes the JSON into a tWelcomeItem (a Card from the Trello API request).

When the SendRequest function in the Cards class runs, it prints the last index of the item in the collection (16 items). This is expected.

However, when I access that collection same from the Storyboard's View Controller, it prints 0 items.

Why is the collection empty when it's instance is being accessed from the View Controller?

**View Controller** - Prints zero items in the collection.

```
private var dm:Cards = Cards(id:"trelloCardID")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    print("* viewDidLoad() *")
    
    print("Total Collection Items: " + String(dm.CardCollection.endIndex))
    
    DataView.dataSource = self
    
    DataView.delegate = self
    
    print("* // viewDidLoad() *")
    
}
```

**Cards Class** - The print line returns 16 items.

```
public class Cards {

var CardCollection = [tWelcomeElement]()
var BoardID:String = ""
var uri:String = ""

let Manager:TrelloHelper = TrelloHelper()

init(id:String) {
    SendRequest(BoardID: id)
    
}

public func SendRequest  (BoardID:String) {
    // SET CLASS PROPERTIES
    self.BoardID = BoardID
    self.uri = "/1/boards/\(self.BoardID)/cards"
    
    // BUILD HTTP REQUEST
    let request:URLRequest = Manager.BuildURL(uri: self.uri, params: "")
    
    // PERFORM HTTP REQUEST
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            
            // CHECK FOR ERRORS
            if let error = error {
                print("Error took place \(error)")
                return
            }
     
            // Convert HTTP Response Data to a String
            if let data = data, let _ = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                
                do {
                        
                    self.CardCollection = try JSONDecoder().decode([tWelcomeElement].self, from: data )
                        
                    print("Total Collection Items:" + String(self.CardCollection.endIndex))
                        
                    } catch {
                    print("Error during JSON serialization: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                    
            } // END-IF
        
    } // END-LET
    
    task.resume()
    
} // END-FUNCTION

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`URLSession` objects make [requests asynchronously](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession). When you init your object and on `viewDidLoad` print the last index of its collectionView your network call should have already started but it is very unlikely to have already completed, hence the reason why you see an `endIndex` of 0.

Comment: How do I wait until the request is complete and collection is filled? Thanks!

Comment: You **shouldn't** halt `viewDidLoad` until you get all the data. Instead you could for instance add UIActivityIndicatorView as you can see in [Apple's guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/app-architecture/loading/).
At the very least I would suggest 1. adding a completion closure to `SendRequest` 2. changing `Cards` initialiser to store the id and not call `SendRequest` 3. add a method `FetchData` to your ViewController and call it in `viewDidLoad` 4. in `FetchData` add an Activity Indicator and call `SendRequest` 5. rm spinner when fetch is complete